# Movie or Series - Identification containing a scene where a boy get murdered by grinding the rear wheel of a motorcycle on his face?

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I can remember seeing a scene of a movie or short series on TV where a man/boy gets murdered by putting his tie or scarf in the rear axle of a dirt-bike or motorcycle and then starting the motor and pulling the throttle, so the person's face gets pulled into the wheel.

Also, I can vaguely remember the killer being possessed or infected by something, making him do commit this gruesome act.

I had seen this scene on TV some 12 to 15 years ago, but the video is probably older.

Comment: I recall hearing about this from a friend when I was (quite a bit) younger, probably about 10 years ago, but never saw the movie myself. I want to say it was based on a Stephen King novel, possibly Pet Sematary, but I can't be certain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure this is [Pet Semetary 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pet_Sematary_2). Per Wikipedia: (Emphasis Mine)

> Jeff and a bully, Clyde (Jared Rushton), get into a fight in a ditch. Jeff is about to have his nose cut off by the spokes of his own bike when Gus shows up. Gus orders Jeff to go home, then **kills Clyde with his own motorcycle (his scarf gets caught in the moving rear-wheel, pulling his head and face into the spokes, tearing it apart) while Drew watches.**

Comment: Awsome, thats the movie! Its incredible how many movies you guys know!